# Need help on setting up matlab to access external c++ compiler

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, mex, sift, winapi

I am currently following SIFTGPU matlab tutorial, and is stuck at this very early section:

> SIFTGPU is coded in C++ and must be saved as a .mex (matlab external)
>   file before it can be called from Matlab. In order to create the .mex
>   file, you must make sure that Matlab is set up to access an external
>   C++ compiler by entering
>
> mex –setup
>
> into the Matlab command window and following the on-screen
>   instructions.

Because I didn't have Visual C++ express 2010 and Windows SDK, I followed the instruction at http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html

The installation of both software are fine, however, when it comes to matlab:

```
>> mex -setup

Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html 

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 
[1] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express in D:\VS2010 

[0] None 

Compiler: 1

Please verify your choices: 

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express  
Location: D:\VS2010 

Are these correct [y]/n? y

***************************************************************************** 
  Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express requires the Microsoft Windows 
         Software Development Kit (SDK), but the SDK cannot be found.  
         For more information about the required SDK, see:  
         http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html 
***************************************************************************** 

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.
```

I am not sure where to go next. Could somebody tell me what do I need to do next after installing VC++ Express 2010 and Windows SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Do not install Visual Studio Express. Install the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) - it comes with a compiler, and that setup works with MATLAB. Visual Studio did not work for me either because of some problems with batch files you need to run to setup the environment.

**Edit** This is the mex configuration screen after you install the SDK:

> mex -setup
>
> Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up
>   a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012a/win64.html
>
> Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files:
>
> Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y
>
> Select a compiler:
>
> [1] Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
>
> [0] None
>
> Compiler:

Comment: @Karl Just as you did, type `mex -setup` and choose the windows compiler. Just do not install VC++ Express. Install only the SDK - there is a compiler there.

Comment: No, there is no compiler listed at all.

Comment: @Karl That is strange. I have updated my answer to show you what configuration options I get. I am no Windows expert, but maybe you installed it in some strange place? Or maybe you chose different installation options? Where did you install it? Do you see it in the start menu?

Comment: ...wait. You got C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0? I thought you said "don't install Visual Studio". Why is it there?

Comment: @Karl this is part of the SDK. I said you should not install Visual Studio Express, only install the SDK _with_ the compilers.

Comment: @Karl Oh I see. You installed the SDK without the compilers. You should install the VC++ compiler environment **that comes with SDK**. You should **not** install the separate package of Visual Studio Express. I hope it is more clear now. You can go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features, right-click on Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows, choose change and mark the Visual c++ compilers..

Comment: Visual C++ compiler is already marked since the beginning, but to double check, I follow your step, and I see that it is still "marked".